# How to render table from json array?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I've JSON array and I need to render it to table using React

```
lockers: [
        { id: 1, status: 0, size: "s" },
        { id: 2, status: 0, size: "m" },
        { id: 3, status: 0, size: "l" },
        { id: 4, status: 0, size: "s" },
        { id: 5, status: 0, size: "m" },
        { id: 6, status: 0, size: "l" },
        { id: 7, status: 0, size: "s" },
        { id: 8, status: 0, size: "m" },
        { id: 9, status: 0, size: "l" },
        { id: 10, status: 0, size: "s" },
        { id: 11, status: 0, size: "m" },
        { id: 12, status: 0, size: "l" },
        { id: 13, status: 0, size: "xl" }
      ]
```

I expect the output like this, please help

```
s    m   l  xl
1    2   3   13
4    5   6   -
7    8   9   -
10   11  12  -
```

Comment: Please, show us your solution so we can use it as starting point for the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

first insert the data into a var like 'data':

```
var data = [
  {id: 1, status: 0, size: 'xl'},
];
```

then create a method to display your json data:

```
class App extends Component {
  displayTable() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p className="Table-header">Table</p>
        <Table1 data={data}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Display your table using the method you've created using 'react-bootstrap-table'

```
class Table1 extends Component {
  displayTable() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BootstrapTable data={this.props.data}>
          <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id'>
            ID
          </TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='status'>
            Status
          </TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='size'>
            Size
          </TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default Table1;